# Google Analytics shows only iOS devices not Android

Tags: android, google-analytics, customization

While checking the GA dashboard it shows Samsung devices along with iOS but when I configure custom dimensions to view the report it shows only the iOS devices not the Android.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After the analysis i found that i am creating duplicate tracker hence the event tracker was not working in android devices but in IOS i did it in right way. In an hybrid model store the tracker as singleton object and use it for tracking. Also we can make the dispatch of collected informations immediately or some specific time.